# Firebase Hosting - unexpected error deploying NextJs app

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

I would like to deploy my NextJs app to Firebase hosting but I am having issues when running `firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only hosting`

I did run `firebase experiments:enable webframeworks` before `firebase init hosting`.

I am unable to deploy from the CLI, through the CI/CD on github or even open the emulators.

System:

- Ubuntu 22.10
- Node version 16.19.1 and npm version 8.19.3 (Using NVM, I have tried other versions)
- Firebase-tools version 11.23.1 (Downloaded using auto install script as per [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-auto-script))
- NextJs version 13.1.6

The `firebase-debug.log` file has the following error:

```bash
[debug] [2023-02-17T21:36:36.278Z] Error: Command failed: npm i --omit dev --no-audit
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:828:11)
    at Object.execSync (node:child_process:899:15)
    at execSync (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:2115:30)
    at prepareFrameworks (/home/rafael/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/index.js:371:42)
    at async deploy (/home/rafael/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:53:13)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

and the npm logs have the following:

```bash
392 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
392 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
392 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
392 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
393 verbose stack Error: inotify@1.4.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
393 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
393 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
393 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
393 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
393 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
394 verbose pkgid inotify@1.4.6
395 verbose cwd /home/rafael/dev/protea/web/.firebase/protea-technology-services/functions
396 verbose Linux 5.19.0-31-generic
397 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/firebase" "/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli" "--script-shell=/home/rafael/.cache/firebase/runtime/shell" "--globalconfig=/home/rafael/.cache/firebase/runtime/npmrc" "--userconfig=/home/rafael/.cache/firebase/runtime/npmrc" "--scripts-prepend-node-path=auto" "i" "--omit" "dev" "--no-audit"
398 verbose node v16.16.0
399 verbose npm  v6.14.18
400 error code ELIFECYCLE
401 error syscall spawn
402 error file /home/rafael/.cache/firebase/runtime/shell
403 error errno ENOENT
404 error inotify@1.4.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
404 error spawn ENOENT
405 error Failed at the inotify@1.4.6 install script.
405 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
406 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This is the **hosting** and **functions** rules in my `firebase.json`:

```json
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: The error appears to be with Python not being available in the build environment. Python is required by node-gyp

Comment: I have Python on my machine. I believe the issue is more closely related to node js and npm versions

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be different behavior depending on how firebase tools is installed. Not sure why though. I fixed it by uninstalling the the firebase CLI, of which i had installed using the command `curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash`, and installed the cli using `npm install -g firebase-tools` instead.I suspect installing it any other way ships the CLI with it's own node version of which might not work your project. But that's just a suspicion. Would love to know what the real reason behind this is. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

What's strange about your firebase.json file is the absence of "public" attribute. Did you omit in on purpose? Firebase hosting docs state that "public" attribute is in fact the only required attribute for hosting whereas "ignore", for example, is optional (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config). According to the docs, "public" attribute specifies which directory to deploy to Firebase Hosting. The default value of "public" is a directory also named "public", but I don't see this attribute in your firebase.json at all.

Comment: I used `firebase init hosting` to set up all the hosting config for the `firebase.json`. I believe the source directory is what is used in place of the public dir. As mentioned above, I got everything to work by simply switching NodeJs versions. I will award the bounty to anyone who can explain why it works on some NodeJs versions and not others, and which versions are stable.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to find a solution. Strange indeed cuz firebase docs state that "source" is used in different attributes called "rewrites" and "redirects", rather than as a substitute for "public".  I used "firebase init hosting" to set up hosting with Node.js v16.15.0 and deploy worked both from the CLI and GitHub Actions CI/CD, but in my case firebase.json has "public", "ignore" and "rewrites" attributes with "source": "**" and "destination": "/index.html" inside of the latter. Firebase docs specify that it's supposed to work with Node.js 14/16/18, but they don't provide any specifics.

Comment: Did you enable the web frameworks experimental feature? I'm using NextJs version 13 which takes a serverside rendering first approach. Firebase enabled cloud functions to allow for serverside react component rendering at the end of last year.

Comment: No, as I recall we installed the CLI then went straight for firebase init hosting, set up everything with CLI prompts, made a local test of firebase deploy, and afterwards had to fine-tune the yaml files to make it deploy on pull request with GitHub Actions (adding some secrets etc). I suppose our setup took place before the feature you speak of was released (we did it approx. in November). Did you file a bug report for this? Maybe they just haven't tested it enough yet

Comment: The feature was only released in November. It is technically still experimental so I expected some bugs. Essentially it allows for server side rendering of static components through Firebase cloud functions. I’ll file a report today

Comment: Not 100% required since you can have either "source" or "public" not both